# How to change "ON/OFF" string data into 0/1?

Tags: python, api

I am monitoring and controlling a smart light bulb from my dashboard(User Interface   Dashboard) and every time I open or close the light bulb it sends back a data that shows the light bulb is on or off, what I want to do is to change this "ON/OFF" data string in to binary of 1/0, is there anyway I can get 1 or 0 instead of 'ON/OFF'.

this is some of the API code I have used to control the light bulb

```
 def identifyDevice(self):
    identifyDeviceResult = False
    print(" {0}Agent for {1} is identifying itself by doing colorloop. Please observe your lights"
          .format(self.variables.get('agent_id', None), self.variables.get('model', None)))
    try:
        devicewasoff = 0
        if self.get_variable('status') == "OFF":
            devicewasoff = 1
            self.setDeviceStatus({"status": "ON"})
        elif self.only_white_bulb:
            self.setDeviceStatus({"status": "OFF"})
        if self.only_white_bulb is False:
            self.setDeviceStatus({"effect": "colorloop"})
        if self.only_white_bulb:
            time_iden = 3
        else:
            time_iden = 10  # time to do identification
        t0 = time.time()
        self.seconds = time_iden
        while time.time() - t0 <= time_iden:
            self.seconds = self.seconds - 1
            print("wait: {} sec".format(self.seconds))
            time.sleep(1)
        self.setDeviceStatus({"effect": "none"})
        if devicewasoff == 1:
            self.setDeviceStatus({"status": "OFF"})
        else:
            self.setDeviceStatus({"status": "ON"})
        identifyDeviceResult = True
    except:
        print("ERROR: classAPI_PhilipsHue connection failure! @ identifyDevice")
    return identifyDeviceResult
```

Comment: FYI, `('on' == 'on')*1` = 1 and `('on' == 'off')*1` = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the returned value is always one of 'ON' or 'OFF', you can use the fact that [`True` and `1` are interchangeable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-boolean-values)

```
result = state == 'ON'
```

If you need some error handling, something like this might work.

```
if state in {'ON', 'OFF'}:
    result = state == 'ON'
else:
    # handle error state
```

If you need an `int` to serialise, call `int` with the result

```
>>> state_on = 'ON'
>>> state_off = 'OFF'
>>> int(state_on == 'ON')
1
>>> int(state_off == 'ON')
0
```

Comment: it didn't work, Am still getting on/off message! is there any other way possible to get the binary data of 1 and 0

Comment: What do you mean binary data of 1 and 0? Is that just the int? Where are you getting the on/off message?

Comment: Yeah I need the int of 1 and 0 instead of on and off, I am sending the data of a smart bulb to a local gateway with MQTT protocol, which published on and off message.

Comment: If you need to ensure it's an actual integer instead of just being usable as one (for sending out of Python) call `int`. I'll update the answer.